# Creating two SOQL search help

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, relationships

My trigger will send an email when an Account has 8 or more Cases created in 7 days.  My first SOQL grabs Cases that fit the criteria. My second SOQL pushes the AccountIds of the Cases into a Set.  My current code gets error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void add(Object) from
>   the type Set

The code

```
    List<AggregateResult> AggregateResultList = [SELECT AccountId, Account.Name name, COUNT(Id) co
                                    FROM Case
                                    WHERE CreatedDate = LAST_N_DAYS:5 
                                    GROUP BY AccountId, Account.Name
                                    HAVING COUNT(Id)  >= 1];

    Set<Id> AcctIds = new Set<Id>();

    for(AggregateResult aggr: AggregateResultList){
        AcctIds.add(aggr.get('AccountId'));  //  <-----HOW DO I ADD ACCOUNT ID TO MY NEW SET????
    }

    List<Case> caseList = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name, Project__r.Implementation_status__c,
    Project__r.Client_Advisor_Email__c FROM Case WHERE AccountId IN :AcctIds];

    System.debug('This is CaseList ' + caseList);


    for(Case cl:caseList){ 
        System.debug('Implementation Status: ' + cl.get('Project__r.Implementation_status__c'));
    }
```

Is there a way to typecast into an Id, or is that even the correct way to go? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your Set is of type of **Id**, you need to cast `aggr.get('AccountId')` to Id.

You can achieve it by

```
AcctIds.add(Id.ValueOf(aggr.get('AccountId')));
```

or

```
Id accId = (Id)aggr.get('AccountId');
AcctIds.add(accId);
```